# Why are one letters edits frowned upon? I often have single letter fixes for LaTeX code

Tags: discussion, editing

I often see people write stuff like `$cos(\theta)$`, were I'd like to a `\`. The system does not let me make such a tiny edit.

Is it so that the peer review queue is not filled with so many edits?

Comment: Simply, there always is something else that you can fix. You are taking up the time of two approvers -- it is better to make it thorough. (Of course, for LaTeX edits not much time is taken; there isn't any need to read the whole post)

Comment: Yeah think about all the time saved if everyone made two edits instead of one. Think abotu the time time saved

Comment: @Raindrop: Definitly. What what if I only see *one* edit?

Comment: Perhaps stackexchange could let users with high reputation make single edits. Perhaps edits by people with high reputation would only need 1 approval instead of 2. Perhaps single letter edits should only require 1 approval instead of 2.

Answer (score 3):

On the larger sites, i.e. the original trilogy, then yes, that is probably the reason. On this site, it doesn't matter so much, but all the sites use the same code, and I don't think the team considers this important enough to allow one-letter edits here. In any case, there should always be something else you can edit at the same time.